# Replace html content with another html content

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I have a JSP page `new.jsp` which has the following content say

```xml
<div class="parentClass">
   <ul>#myLinks</ul>
 </div>
 <a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="seeAll">More</a>
```

I have to replace the `#myLinks` with another HTML that I generate in my action class. I read the content of the JSP page using htmlReader which is working correctly. But I tried using replaceAll function to replace my unwanted content. `myPage` contains the content of my JSP page.

`subLinks` content is a follows

```xml
<li>abc</li>
<li>abc</li>
<li>abc</li>
<li>abc</li>
```

But even after using this, the output of `replacedContent` is the same.

```java
replacedContent = myPage.replaceAll("#myLinks", subLinks);
```

I need the final output as

```xml
<div class="parentClass">
   <ul>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>abc</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="seeAll">More</a>
```

Could someone help me on this.

Comment: Why are you replacing a string instead of just printing the content at the right place? ie. using `<%@ include file="filename" %> `

Comment: @Dennis Would like to explain it to u ,but its a long story.. :)

Comment: It workds. Try    `System.out.println("<ul>#myLinks</ul>".replaceAll("#myLinks",
            "<li>abc</li><li>abc</li><li>abc</li><li>abc</li>"));`

Comment: @Braj yep that workd.But my issue is still there

Comment: `Would like to explain it to u ,but its a long story.. :)` **WE WANT THE LONG STORY (short) :)** and more details too: do you need to change the HTML, the DOM, or the visibility of that section ? Or do you need to alter the JSP before it's rendered to HTML ? What exactly are you trying to achieve and why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ways to do it, but the most simple way is to use some property or method in the action class that returns a string which contains a generated html. Then you you can write this HTML directly to the out.

```xml
<ul><s:property value="%{subLinks}" escapeHtml="false" /></ul>
```

of course you should provide a getter for `subLinks` property.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using javascript.
First give some id to sublink container tag `<ul id="test">`

then hope you get sublinks as string. like sublinks = "`<li>abc</li><li>abc</li>...`"

Now write following javascript code at last in body.

`<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = sublinks;
</script>`

That's it.

Hope this will be helpful to you.